# How to wait for app to close before starting a new instance with webpack hot module reload?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, nestjs, webpack-hmr

I'm using webpack hot module reload (hmr) for my nest.js application. The reload works but doesn't wait for the old instance to close fully (database connection, telegram bot,...) before starting up a new instance. This makes typeorm throw the following error:

```
AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.
```

In my `main.ts` I have a dispose handler that closes the old instance:

```
if (module && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.dispose(async () => {
    console.log('disposing module');
    await app.close();
    console.log('has closed app');
  });
}
```

When I run hmr and make a change to my app, I can see that it calls the dispose handler and immediately starts up the new application. How can I make webpack wait for the promise to resolve that is returned by the dispose handler before starting the new instance?

Comment: <Webpack n00b>What if you call `accept` in `dispose`'s callback, _after_ the `await`?</Webpack n00b>

Comment: From one noob to another... ;-) Yes, I've tried that already and unfortunately, this doesn't work. It will fail on the initial start because the module has to `accept` itself even before a change happens. Also, I think it starts the application first and then `accepts` itself. I'm afraid that hmr just isn't intended to wait (it's supposed to be quick right?! ;)) So the solution probably is to handle all the resources that can only be acquired once as is possible for the database connection. Now I have to figure out how to handle my bot... Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Comment: _fail on the initial start_: if you think only the first pass would fail, then it's possible to flag the calls? Something like `if (!m.hot.hasDispose) m.hot.accept();` then in the callback `m.hot.accept(); m.hot.hasDispose = true;`? (Or maybe use another object to hold the flag, no idea whether this `module.hot` persists.) Anyway, good luck, it's weird that no one seems to have addressed this issue without altering lower layers like this `TypeOrm` workaround...

Comment: Hi, ever found a solution to this? I run into a similar issue with Apollo Universal Starter Kit when startup takes to much time, I get an EADDRINUSE when the new server starts so I guess the first one is not actually closed ([code here](https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/stable/modules/core/server-ts/server.ts))

Comment: @EricBurel I'm afraid not, for typeorm the `keepConnectionAlive` helped, in the other case it's just a log message that I'm ignoring. Maybe you can find a similar option in your case. I don't think there is a generic solution available.

Comment: Hi, eventually the issue for me was using Yarn 0.12.x, which has issues with children signals. So the `module.hot.dispose` callback was not even called in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/711#issuecomment-392028717), you can set `keepConnectionAlive` to `true` in the typeorm options for it to reuse the connection.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  // ...
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
})
```

This does solve the typeorm error but the problem with the telegram bot persists:

```
Error: 409: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

I don't think I can reuse the bot instance, so this is only a partial solution.

Comment: It's worked for me. I am using NestJS + webpack hot load.